# I need to show the array in an Angular project with firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

I cant make work this code so far i think it has to be something with the subscribe method but im not sure its from a course

i have problems with this code it says this: No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(observerOrNext?: Partial<Observer> | ((value: Object) => void) | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
Argument of type '(persons: Person[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<Observer> | ((value: Object) => void) | undefined'.
Type '(persons: Person[]) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: Object) => void'.
Types of parameters 'persons' and 'value' are incompatible.
The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Person[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.
Overload 2 of 2, '(next?: ((value: Object) => void) | null | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | null | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | null | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
Argument of type '(persons: Person[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
Types of parameters 'persons' and 'value' are incompatible.
Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'Person[]'.
The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.personsService.obtainPeople()
    .subscribe(
      (persons: Person[]) => {
      return this.persons = persons;
    }
    
    );
```

Comment: i have removed the return and still does not work

Comment: I resolved it. by changing the type of person to any: 
```ngOnInit(): void {
    this.personsService.obtainPeople()
    .subscribe(
      (persons: any) => {
      return this.persons = persons;
    }
    
    );